# Cannot remove meta box added through OOP

Tags: metabox, oop

Please do no mark this question as duplicated or downvote as I tried every code found on all docs (old and new), all the websites, forums etc, but nothing worked for me...

I added the meta box through the code found here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/#oop

Then I went to a post and changed the value of the select to 'Something' and saved the post

Now I need to remove the meta box, but I am not able to figure how in any way...

```
remove_meta_box('wporg_box_id', ['post', 'wporg_cpt'], 'advanced');
```

- I tried to fire it at different **events** like `admin_menu` and `do_meta_boxes` as described [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_meta_box/#comment-569) for example
- I tried to use different **context** like `advanced`,`normal` or none...
- I tried different **id** values like `wporg_box_id` and `_wporg_meta_key`
- I tried different **screens** like `['post', 'wporg_cpt']` and `'post'`

but nothing worked... Please can you explain how can I remove it?

The way I am actually getting it is (inside single.php):

```
echo '<pre>', print_r( get_post_meta( $post->ID ) ), '</pre>';
```

and it keeps showing me this:

```
Array
(
    [_edit_last] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [_edit_lock] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1513844245:1
        )

    [_wporg_meta_key] => Array
        (
            [0] => something
        )

)
1
```

Comment: Just to be sure: Are you trying to remove the MetaBox from the screen or to remove the value from the post meta?

Comment: @Andrei Completely remove it... So both screen and post meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the function [remove_meta_box](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/#removing-meta-boxes) is meant to handle only the UI part, it only removes the metabox from the screen.

If you want to also delete the post metadata for that specific key you will need to use [delete_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/managing-post-metadata/#deleting-metadata) function.

Comment: yes Andrei thank to even your previous comment I was able to do it! :) Thank you so much, it makes sense now. Will accept as soon as possible! :)